# Access Moodle webservices

Tags: json, web-services, moodle

I am trying to communicate with a moodle2 instance via json web service protocol. I can't get it working, no matter how long I tried. I generated an API key which I use for calling the following url in my browser:

```
http://<moodle base url>/webservice/rest/server.php?wsfunction=get_course_contents&wstoken=<api key>&courseid=916
```

As there seems to be no developer documentation for accessing the API I read the source code and found the required param `coursed` for this function.

Calling this URL in my browser results in a white window - server returns simply nothing but accepts my url (no 404 or something similar). The server part must be up and running because the official Moodle app can somehow communicate with the instance.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a developer documentation listing all functions and their params?

Comment: Hey please where did you get Api Key for moodle? Thanks!

Comment: See http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Creating_a_web_service_client "how to get a token"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem was our organization not allowing me to view the administrative backend. It includes a full documentation of all functions and services.

Regrettably this documentation is not mentioned anywhere on the internet (especially not on the noodle wiki / site).